# WebdriverIO and Docker Setup

Tags: php, docker, webdriver-io

I am trying to setup a docker container with WebdriverIO built into it, with the eventual aim of being able to run a CI/CD pipeline in gitlab, but I have absolutely no idea where to start.

My application is a PHP/MySQL based app which was also recently dockerised. I access it locally on http://localhost.

I have tried to create a docker image with wdio built into it, but it fails when trying to do the

```
npm init wdio --yes
```

as the --yes command doesn't force any of the default settings, which goes against the official documentation. This then causes the wdio installation to fail.

What is confusing me even more is that there seems to be very few tutorials for this, the wdio documentation doesn't seem great, and what tutorials I can find all seem to mention selenium. FYI, I am just a dev that has been tasked to take some existing WDIO scripts and get them ready for CI/CD, I don't know a massive amount about WDIO in the first place.

Does anyone have any basic steps I could follow that would describe the process of taking some local WDIO scripts, and getting them to run inside a container, with the end goal of being to have them into some sort of CI/CD pipeline?

When trying to create the image, the following command does not seem to work:

```
npm init wdio --yes
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more appropriate if you have initialize a wdio project and copy it to the Dockerfile.

This is what it might look like:

```
FROM node:16
USER root

#===============================
# Set default workspace
#===============================
RUN mkdir /home/workspace \
&& chmod 2777 /home/workspace
COPY . /home/workspace
WORKDIR /home/workspace
```

This way, your docker image contains your whole project built in.

Then you could append the following command to make sure the environment is ready for webdriverI/O to execute.

```
#==================================
# Install needed packages
#==================================
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN npm install
```

If you need anything like browser and webdriver, you could install it via dozens of approaches.

You can use **ENTRYPOINT** or **CMD** to make it execute the specified test suites once the container is up.

If you wanna complete CI or CD flow with docker containers, it will depend on which service you may utilize.